# How to use Plug.Upload?

Tags: elixir

I would like to use `Plug.Upload` in one of my routers without any library or framework on top but the official documentation here: https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Upload.html does not provide an example unlike for other plugs such as: `Plug.Parsers` (https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.html).

Can someone gives an example ?

Comment: Also, `Plug.Upload` is not a plug, it’s a struct returned by `Plug.Parsers.MULTIPART` plug to represent the uploaded file (and `GenServer` handling the transfers.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Plug.Upload` is not a plug, as Aleksei mentioned in comments. You can't add it to your pipeline. Instead, `:multipart` should be allowed in `Plug.Parsers` configuration in your `endpoint.ex` (it's there by default):

```rb
plug Plug.Parsers,
  parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart, :json],
  pass: ["*/*"],
  json_decoder: Phoenix.json_library()
```

You'll need a route for handling a POST request with the uploaded file:

```rb
post "/upload_photo", UploadController, :photo
```

Respective controller action will get a `Plug.Upload` struct inside one of its parameters:

```rb
def photo(conn, %{"upload" => upload}) do
  IO.inspect upload.photo, label: "Photo upload information"
  # TODO: you can copy the uploaded file now,
  #       because it gets deleted after this request
  json(conn, "Uploaded #{upload.photo.filename} to a temporary directory")
end
```

For testing, you can add a page that has a form with `multipart: true`

```rb
<%= form_for @conn, "/upload_photo", [as: :upload, multipart: true], fn f -> %>
```

which has a file input

```rb
<%= file_input f, :photo, class: "form-control" %>
```

Detailed instructions are provided in the [Phoenix framework docs](https://phoenixframework.readme.io/docs/file-uploads).

Comment: Thank you and @Aleksei. I'm not using Phoenix but will use this example as a reference

Comment: https://www.poeticoding.com/step-by-step-tutorial-to-build-a-phoenix-app-that-supports-user-uploads/

Comment: Here is what I've done finally:  
1. Register the Parsers plug:  
`plug Plug.Parsers,  parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart],  pass: ["*/*"]`  
2. The uploaded file is accessible under: `conn.body_params["image"]` where `image` is the key of the file in the request